# How to select a text between 2 different tags in the dom?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, querypath

I have a `<p>` tag which contains text separated by `<br>` tags like this:

```
<p>
    <small>Some text here</small>
    This is the text that want to remove
    <br> another text here
    <br> more text here
    <br> also there are other tags like <em>this one</em>
</p>
```

The elements that I want to select are after the first `<br>` tag until the end, I'm currently using the [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) library and I'm only getting the html tags and the text between them and not getting the other text which is not surrounded by tags.

for example I get only the `<br>` tags and the `<em></em>` tag with this code:

```
$qp->find('div > p')->children('br')->eq(0)->nextAll();
```

So I tried to get the whole `<p>` tag and try to remove the elements from the `<small>` tag until the first `<br>` tag:

```
// remove the text after the small tag
$qp->branch('div > p')->children('small')->textAfter(''); // didn't work

// although when I return the textAfter I get the text
// so setting it to an empty string didn't work

// I can only remove the small tag
$qp->branch('div > p')->children('small')->remove();
```

The QueryPath library is a wrapper on top of the [Dom](http://php.net/Dom) native extension, so any solution using the Dom extension will work.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @AmalMurali I need all the elements including the text after the first `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The QueryPath-methods used for the selection of nodes(e.g. `nextAll()` or `children()`) only return ElementNodes, but the nodes between the `<br/>`-elements are TextNodes.

Use the `nextSibling`-property of DOMNode to select TextNodes too.

Example(using native DOM):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadXML('<p>
    <small>Some text here</small>
    This is the text that want to remove
    <br/> another text here
    <br/> more text here
    <br/> also there are other tags like <em>this one</em>
</p>');
$text='';
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('br')->item(0);
while($node->nextSibling){
  $node=$node->nextSibling;
  $text.=$node->textContent;
}
echo $text;
//output:
//another text here more text here also there are other tags like this one 
?>
```

Comment: And how can I get also the tags like the `<em>` and other `<br>` tags ?

Comment: Use $node to access the nodes(element or text)